# How to show all associated items in json_response in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I'm working on an API based Rails application, I don't know how to show all associated items in one request like my models

todo.rb

```
class Todo < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
    validates_presence_of :title, :created_by
end
```

item.rb

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :todo
    validates_presence_of :name
end
```

in the controller

```
def show
    json_response(@todo)
end

private
def set_todo
    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])
end
```

The endpoit for single todo

```
https://example.com/todos/1
```

and it showing like this

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Hello World!",
    "created_by": "2",
    "created_at": "2018-04-26T11:19:31.433Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-04-26T11:19:31.433Z"
}
```

My question is how do I show all `items` which created by this todo in same end point request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON#as_json](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html#method-i-as_json)

For e.g.

```
def show
  render json: @user.as_json(include: :posts), status: 200
end
```

That should return a response like

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Konata Izumi",
  "age": 16,
  "created_at": "2006/08/01",
  "awesome": true,
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "author_id": 1,
      "title": "Welcome to the weblog"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "author_id": 1,
      "title": "So I was thinking"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def show
  render json: {"todos" => {"todo" => @todo, "items" => @todo.items }}, status:200
end
```

Alternatively you can use [serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-8-stable) for more filters and modifications of response datas

Comment: It's working but I think **JiggneshhGohel** answer is some standard. Thanks :) +1